# How does temperature affect photosynthesis?

Tags: photosynthesis

I am doing a lab for biology and my teacher required me to do this virtual lab. However, it does not make sense when seeing the results of the lab. In 30 second trials, it shows that there are 16 bubbles at 10C, 6 bubbles at 25C and 19 at 40C. This should not happen as 25C is near the optimal temperature (at least in respiration) but it shows the opposite.

Is the site wrong or am I wrong?

Site link: http://www.kscience.co.uk/animations/photolab.htm

Constants: 50 Light intensity, full disolved co2, white light color.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. I am afraid that questions here have to be self-contained. A link to a reference is OK, but readers cannot be expected to go to another site to  find out what the question is. At present the question is not clear. What is the design of the experiment, what are the bubbles supposed to be, and where is it stated that photosynthesis should be optimal at 25C? You need to clarify your question.

Comment: It doesn’t look like the link is working for me on iOS - can you add a bit more information or a screenshot to demonstrate what the lab looks like?

Answer (score -1):

Your experiment should look something like this: [The effect of temperature on photosynthetic rate of Elodea (pondweed)](https://bnwkepler62e.wordpress.com/2015/03/24/the-effect-of-temperature-on-photosynthetic-rate-of-elodea-pondweed/). I assume you used Elodea canadensis for your test. Maybe the plant is already a bit "exhausted" - try to take a different branch. Or maybe it needs more time to get used to the new temperature.